# Is it possible to make a dynamic sql statement based on combobox.value in access?

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-forms

I made a form in access with 2 different comboboxes. The user of
This tool can choose in combobox1: the table (which has to be filtered) and the second combobox2 is the criteria to be filtered( for example Language= “EN”) and the output of this query has to be located in tablex.

The problen what I have is that i cant find a solution for passing the value of the combobox1 to the sql statement. The second one is just like: where [language] = forms!form!combo2.value, but the part where i cant find a solution for is: select * from (combobox1 value)? How can i pass the combobox value as table name to be filtered? Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can't have the table name in the `WHERE` clause of your query (there might be a hacky way to do it, but it should be discouraged at any case).

If you want to select data from 1 of a number of tables, your best bet is to generate SQL dynamically using VBA. One way to do this (especially if you want/need your query to open in Datasheet View for the end user) is to have a "dummy" query whose SQL you can populate using the form selections.

For example, let's say we have 2 tables: `tTable1` and `tTable2`. Both of these tables have a single column named `Language`. You want the user to select data from either the first or second table, with an optional filter.

1. Create a form with 2 combo boxes: One for the tables, and one with the criteria selections. It sounds like you've already done this step.
2. Have a button on this form that opens the query. The code for this button's `press` event should look something like this:

   ```
   Private Sub cmdRunQuery_Click()
       Dim sSQL As String
       Dim db As DAO.Database
       Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef

       If Not IsNull(Me.cboTableName.Value) Then
           sSQL = "SELECT * FROM " & Me.cboTableName.Value

           If Not IsNull(Me.cboFilter.Value) Then
               sSQL = sSQL & vbNewLine & _
                       "WHERE Language=""" & Me.cboFilter & """"
           End If

           Set db = CurrentDb
           Set qdf = db.QueryDefs("qDummyQuery")
           qdf.SQL = sSQL

           DoCmd.OpenQuery qdf.Name
       End If
   End Sub
   ```

Note how the SQL is being generated. Of course, using this method, you need to protect yourself from SQL injection: You should only allow predefined values in the combo box. But this serves as a proof of concept.

If you don't need to show the query results, you don't need to use the dummy query: You could just open a recordset based on the SQL and process that.

Answer (score 0):

If you run the code in the afterupdate event of the combobox you can set an SQL statement like this:

```
Private Sub combobox2_AfterUpdate()
   someGlobalVar = "Select * FROM " & me.combobox1.value & " WHERE language = " & _
         me.combobox2.value
End Sub
```

And then call the global with the SQL string wherever you need it.